# set_post_thumbnail_size has no effect - always 200x300 size is generated

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have set thumbnail size.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
set_post_thumbnail_size( 145, 170);
```

This is called during after_setup_theme.
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ales_setup' );

However, when I upload image and see thumbnail, it always shows me 200x300 thumbnail. It is not related to regenerating of image, because I am trying to upload new image via Media Uploader and the reuslt is 200x300 image + it is cropped.

Original image is 3560 x 3196 size. What I was expected that image would be resized vertically and horizontally accordingly.

Comment: I do not recommend upload images with sizes as large as your example (3k x 3k px). To control this I recommend the plugin [Imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/faq/) This plugin resize the image when uploading.

Comment: You can also change thumbnail settings in backend.
/wp-admin/options-media.php

Comment: @nicogaldo this is another issue (about large image), I am not asking about htis, I ask only about thumbnail.

Comment: @user5200704 it is not good practice to change it via backend, I wonder why wordpress functionality doesn't work.

Comment: set_post_thumbnail_size function make a new size post-thumbnail. It will not changed wordpress default sizes like thumbnail, medium or large.When you get image using this function the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail').
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

 get_intermediate_image_sizes() this function to check all registered images sizes,

Comment: you are using the plugin "regenerate thumbnails" that rebuilds the thumbnails after you change the size? I think that if they change sizes from the backend (/wp-admin/options-media.php) should work

Answer (score 0):

`add_image_size` works fine for me.

Try this:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 145, 170 )
```

If you need to cut image:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 145, 170, true );
```

To understand it better read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size#Examples)

Comment: But in this case I have to modify all the theme, I want to modify default thumbnail size to be 145 x 170, I do not with to create custom-size and modify everywhere where I get thumbnails.